# passing placeholder value to dependency jar bean configuration

Tags: java, dependency-injection, spring-boot, web-config, property-placeholder

Hi I am developing a `spring boot` application which has a dependency on another project say `B`. The dependency jar of `B` has config file for all the bean injections. Now when I am creating a bean of class in project `B` in my project the definitions of dependent beans has to be added to hence repeating the configuration in project `B` in my configuration file. To avoid that I just added the project `B` configuration file to my classpath.

Project `B` has a class say `ClassEX` which has `contructor` arguments as `argA` and `argB`. When i am trying to pass the value to these using my placeholder configuration it is failing to read it and throwing exception as .

```
Cannot cast null to int type
```

So basically the value is coming null.

I tried creating the bean of same class by putting it in in my project and it is working fine and reading the placeholder values.

For below example `projectAbean` is getting created but `projectBbean` is failing.

Can anyone tell what could be the reason.Below are my configurations:
    project A `config.xml`

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/ce.env.properties" />
<import resource="classpath:/projectB-config.xml" />
<bean id="projectAbean" class="com.ex.projecta.ClassEX">
<constructor-arg type="String" value="${argA}" />
<constructor-arg type="String" value="${argB}" />
</bean>
properties file:
argA=20
argB=10

projectB-config.xml
<bean id="projectBbean" class="com.ex.projectb.ClassEX">
<constructor-arg type="String" value="${argA}" />
<constructor-arg type="String" value="${argB}" />
</bean>
exception:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: 
Could not convert argument value of type [null] to required type [int]: 
Failed to convert value of type [null] to required type [int]; nested 
exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of 
type [null] to required type [int]: PropertyEditor 
[org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned 
inappropriate value of type [null] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot, the best approach is generally to make your B project auto-configured (add its base configuration to a file in `META-INF`).

Comment: For Spring > 3.1 your example should work. Nonetheless -- have you tried adding the property placeholder also to `projectB-config.xml`?

Comment: No I did not, I cant modify projectB configuraion. But is that required because both project a and b config file is in classpath and both would be referencing to the same context. Project a already have it declared.